# PageRoute transition with rounded corners

Tags: flutter, dart, page-transition

I'd like to have the card in my carousel to keep the rounded corners on the page transition to the new page. At the moment it get's square corners the moment I click to navigate to a new page.

Is there any way to keep them rounded like they are on the return of the below gif

[image]

I have tried wrapping the entire scaffold of the new page in a clipRect but that only makes the new page rounded once the transition is complete.

The page consist of a carousel_slider with a container (onTap) with a hero animation on the new page that is pushed using pushTransparentRoute from the dismissible_page plugin.